# merge the second data frame into the first one

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge, concatenation

I want to merge 2 data frames as follows:

```
left:

   A  B  C  D    E    F    G    H     
   1  2  3  4    5    6    7    h       
   5  2  3  4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  
   1  2  4  4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  


right:
   E  F  G  H     
   1  2  g  h2
```

I wanted to do:

```
merge=pd.merge(left=left,right=right,left_on=['A','B'], right_on=['E','F'],how='left')
```

But I want something that looks like this:

```
   A  B  C  D    E    F    G    H     
   1  2  3  4    5    6    7    h
   1  2  3  4    1    2    g    h2
   5  2  3  4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  
   1  2  4  4    1    2    g    h2
```

Any idea how I can achieve the desired result?

Many thanks!!

Comment: I think I figured out myself... I can do a subset `left2=left[['A','B','C','D']]` and do a merge with `right`, then concat with `left` and then drop duplicates

Answer (score 0):

You may need consider `update`

```
left=left.set_index(['A','B'])
right.index=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([right['E'],right['F']])
left.update(right)
left.reset_index(inplace=True)
left
Out[274]: 
   A  B  C  D    E    F    G    H
0  1  2  3  4  1.0  2.0    g   h2
1  5  2  3  4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  1  2  4  4  1.0  2.0    g   h2
```